# entity level validator not triggered

Tags: breeze

I've observed that when I'm adding an entity to a collection of another entity, the validator for the second entity is not called.

I expected that adding to a child collection triggers entity level validation on the parent when savechanges is called.

I can't write a test right now, but if needed I'll would write it this afternoon.

Is this the expected behaviour or a bug?

```
entity.OrderLine().arrayChanged.subscribe(function (args) {
        console.log(args);
        if (args.added && args.added.some(function (element) {
            console.log(element.entityAspect.entityState.name);
            return !(element.entityAspect.entityState.isUnchanged() 
                || element.entityAspect.entityState.isDeleted());
        })) {
            console.log("modifico");
            entity.entityAspect.setModified();
        }
        if (args.removed && args.removed.some(function (element) {
             console.log(element.entityAspect.entityState.name);
            return !element.entityAspect.entityState.isAdded();
        })) {
            console.log("modifico");
            entity.entityAspect.setModified();
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The parent is not changed automatically by the addition of a child because no data property of the parent changes. That is the technical reason.

Sometimes (often?) the model semantics say that the parent **is** changed by any addition/deletion/change-to a child. That is not always true which is why Breeze doesn't propagate the change automatically. But it is often true ... and I think it would be a good idea for Breeze to support this for you if you specify this as desired behavior in the metadata. You are not alone in wanting this.

I've added [**a User Voice suggestion for this idea**](http://breezejs.uservoice.com/forums/173093-breeze-feature-suggestions/suggestions/3644789-can-configure-a-parent-entity-type-to-enter-the-mo); please vote for it if it (and add your comments) if it matters to you.

Meanwhile, in an [entity initializer](http://www.breezejs.com/documentation/extending-entities) you can subscribe to changes in the parent collection and to the items of that collection and have them set the parent to the "Modified" state (`parent.entityAspect.setModified()`). This will have to do for now I'm afraid.

Comment: Hello, just one question: In the parent entity, i'm doing a subscription to the arrayChanged event from the child collection : entity.OrderLine().arrayChanged.subscribe(...); and i'm observing that, if an order line is deleted and rejectChanges is called, inside of the added array at the args variable, the entityState of the order line is Deleted. I expected it to be Unmodified. ¿It's this behaviour correct?  I've updated the question to show you the subscription.

Comment: It should be unmodified and have been restored to the array. I thought I saw a test for that scenario. Maybe I'm dreaming. Do you have one? Thanks.

Comment: I think that we are not talking about the same array. The observable array is updated correctly. I'm talking about the arrays passed to the subscribe function: args.added and args.removed.